# Prove that $\text{argmin}_x f(x) \leq \text{argmin}_x (f(x) - mx)$ for any $f(x)$ and $m\geq0$

Tags: optimization

How to prove that $\text{argmin}_x f(x) \leq \text{argmin}_x (f(x) - mx)$ for any function $f(x)$ and $m\geq0$?

Comment: This might just be my lack of background in optimization, but what is the definition of $\operatorname{argmin}$?

Comment: Please see the [Wikipedia article for **argmax**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argmax) (**argmin** is defined analogously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $y = \mathrm{argmin}_x f(x)$ and $z = \mathrm{argmin}_x (f(x) - mx)$. Write inequalities for $f(y)$ and $f(z)$ and for $f(y)-my$ and $f(z)-mz$.

Comment: My solution:

Let $g(x) = f(x) - mx$ and $y = \text{argmin}_x f(x), z = \text{argmin}_x g(x)$.
Then we have
$f(z) \geq f(y)$ because $f(y) = \min_x f(x)$
and also
$g(z) \leq g(y)$ because $g(z) = \min_x g(x)$
Putting it all together (assuming $m>0$, case $m=0$ trivial anyway):
\begin{align}
g(y) &\geq g(z) \\
f(y)-my &\geq f(z)-mz \\
f(y)-my &\geq f(y)-mz \\
-my &\geq -mz \\
y &\leq z \\
\text{argmin}_x f(x) &\leq \text{argmin}_x (f(x) - mx) \\
\end{align}